# Tests execution lasts for a lot of time because of embedded Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, junit, spring-test

We use Spring test, JUnit and embedded Elasticsearch in our *integration* tests. The problem is that there are a lot of test classes so embedded Elasticsearch starts and stops for a lot of times. So 90% of test execution time we wait for Elasticsearch.

- What is the best practice to avoid this situation? Launch separate Elasticsearch for test?
- Is it possible to write any JUnit config to start embedded Elasticsearch once before all tests and shut down after all tests? I'm looking to something like @BeforeAll annotation but for all classes, not one.

Comment: Why you didn't use mocks to simulate the elastic search behavior?

Comment: It's integration tests. We can mock the response of ES but it would be better to test using the results from ES.

Comment: I don't know which embedded elastic are you using, but normally you can define an abstract class where you define the embedded elastic in a BeforeAll and than extend it in the integration tests classes